# How to convert sharepoint site pages to pdf

Tags: pdf, third-party-software, document-converter

Is there any 3rd party tool available that would convert SharePoint pages to PDF or any custom code that converts pages to pdf?

Answer (score 1):

You can check a tool from Muhimbi called PDF converter.

- [PDF Converter for SharePoint](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint.aspx) they offer trial version so you can try it.

Also have a look on this one; https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/thomsven/2011/09/09/export-sharepoint-wiki-to-wordpdf-without-3rd-party-tools/

Comment: I can vouch for the Muhimbi tool. It does the conversions well

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use a "Print to PDF" tool. There are a few programs that can do this:

- In Windows 10, "Microsoft Print to PDF" is built in
- Google Chrome has that functionality built in
- [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/) - A free program I have used for years that works with just about any OS
- [Web2PDF](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/) - Convert externally available websites to PDF without needing to install anything. Never used this before, just found it after a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to write some custom code, a good option is [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). I've been using it for years and you can dynamically create PDFs pretty easily:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c:\\my.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string htmlText =     wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:59500/my.html");
        Response.Write(htmlText);
        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new    StringReader(htmlText), null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }

        document.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf